# Selenium Chrome 3.5.3 Alerts

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, alerts

Just a question about Selenium 3.5.3 and handling alerts...

I got the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open
```

...although I set this code:

```
...
chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Selenium\\Conf\\ChromeProfile");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://" + webdriverChromeUser + ":" + webdriverChromePassWd + "@" + webdriverChromeProxy);
chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");

chromCapability.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
chromCapability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

remWebDriver = new org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), chromCapability);
...
```

I would expect, that it works, but the error comes up.

Comment: Two questions: 1 - Where the exception is thrown. 2 - Why do expect it should work?

Comment: I read somewhere, that the setting:works....   

chromCapability.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);

No exception is thrown ...